# Uploadify - Convert Image while uploading

Tags: uploadify

I was wondering is there any way to convert any image file extention to jpg while uploading using uploadify.I have searched a lot and couldnt find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add some code in the uploadify.php file to convert any image to jpg **after** uploading, around

```
move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
```

Have a look into [GD](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or [ImageMagick](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php).

Comment: For a detailed explanation I do not have enough information, as this depends on the php version you have installed, which modules are available, also the expected input is of relevance in case you don't have imagemagick installed, which can convert most image formats. There are many different ways to achieve this and the links I posted earlier should point you in the right direction.